# Converting json data to python dictionary

Tags: python, json, spotify

Im working with the spotify api. Found a tutorial since ive never worked with api's before. I did exactly as he did but im getting errors.
Tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAmEZBEeNmg&t=250s&ab_channel=Linode
part im stuck on is at 12:30

When i run this:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import base64
import requests
from requests import post
import json

load_dotenv()

clientID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
clientSecret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")


def get_token():
    auth_string = str(clientID) + ':' + str(clientSecret)
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")
    
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization" : "Basic" + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {"grant_type" : "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers = headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token

token = get_token()
print(token)
```

I have an issue with the token = json_result["access_token"]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\asdf\main.py", line 30, in <module> 
    token = get_token()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\asdf\main.py", line 27, in get_token
    token = json_result["access_token"]
            ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

Any help is much appreciated. Also im using vs code if that makes a difference

Comment: Can you show us the full contents of `json_result`?

Comment: Also, it's better to use `result.json()` instead of `json.loads(result.content)`.

Comment: `result = post(url, headers = headers, data=data)`
`json_result = result.json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing a space between `Basic` and `auth_base64`

From

```
"Authorization" : "Basic" + auth_base64,
```

To

```
"Authorization" : "Basic " + auth_base64,
```

Comment: you're the goat